# Tkinter - Align images using relative offsett on canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating my own version of Crazy Eights. All the logic behind the app is fine but I am getting trouble placing my cards in the canvas. Actually, my app works well when I set a specific size for my main windows/canvas (800x800). However, I wanted my app gets the screen size of the device it is running and resize the main window. I achieved that by adding the following lines:

```
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
```

Everything is fine until this point but then I have some troubles trying to re-center (align) my cards horizontally and vertically. For example: For one hand, all cards are placed using absolute offset (x, 700); where x will increase in order to give distant between cards and 700 is the position in the y coordinate. But using absolute offset only work when the window size is fixed. Therefore, I wanted to use relative offset like rely and relx (place geometry) but I do not know how to do it. Here I post an image to give you an idea what happened and what I want.

[image]

Here is my script:

```
import tkinter as tk

class start_gui(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self.hand = dict()
    # create canvas
    self.w, self.h = parent.winfo_screenwidth(), parent.winfo_screenheight()
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(parent, width=self.w, height=self.h, background="red")

    self.x = 280
    self.playerHand = self.gethand()
    # display for south
    for Card in playerHand:
        self.hand[(self.canvas.create_image(self.x, 700, image=self.getImage(Card[0], Card[1]), tags='p1'))] = [
            Card[0], Card[1], sel.x, 700]
        self.x += 20
        # print(str(Card.suit))

def gethand(self):
    # here goes some script to get player card hand
    # return a list of lists

def getImage(self, num, suit):
    # return image item

if __name__ == "__main__":
root = tk.Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
start_gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Also, I want to create a function to re-center (align) my cards after a click event. I post another image to give you an idea.
[image]

From the image above, if we make click on one square. The chosen square will be place in the middle of the canvas and the other cards will align horizontally maintaining the initial space between cards. If once again we make click again, the previous event will take place and so on.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to making your window the size of your device's screen, I would recommend using the attributes feature of root to make it fullscreen, and expanding the canvas to fill the size of the window.

This would look something like:

```
root = Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True) #Makes the window fullscreen.

...

self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, bg="red", highlightthickness=0)
    #Highlight thickness makes the canvas have no border in fullscreen mode.
self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True) #Use pack to make canvas take up full window.
```

What this would do is make your canvas take up the entire screen.
Either after calling your mainloop, or using root.update(), you can get the full size of your canvas/window (which are now the same) via using `self.canvas.winfo_width()` and `self.canvas.winfo_height()`.

Now with a fullscreen canvas as you wanted, you could go about card generation in the right position with the screen width, as defined earlier. With a variable denoting the cards with, and a second variable acting as the buffer size between each card, you could do something along the lines of

```
start_pos = screen_width/2 - (buffer_width*card_width)*num_of_cards/2 #Gets first x coord
y_pos = [screen_height-card_height*2, screen_height-card_height]      #makes 2 y coords
for i in range(num_of_cards):
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(start_pos+(i*(card_width+buffer_width)), y_pos[0], start_pos+card_width+buffer_width+(i*(card_width+buffer_width)), y_pos[1], fill = card_colours[i]) #Make list of card colours in order
```

(Sorry for the long last line!)

This is just a brief bit of code to demonstrate one way you could use the width to create cards centered about the middle, regardless of how many cards there are. You may need to tinker with it a bit to get it how you want.

I hope this helps, good luck!